# What is "Pledge" in Magitech Chronicles RPG

Tags: spells, spellcasting, magitech-chronicles

Recently I acquired the Magitech Chronicles RPG book and I'm really confused what Pledge spellpool means, I searched all around the book and there is no clear explanation.

See, some spells have a cost, you use Lighting Bolt you pay 1 from your spellpool, other's have a cost and that cost also gets "pledged". Does that mean that while the spell is going I can't recover that amount of spellpool? Anyone knows?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Do the spells which use Pledge have a duration beyond the immediate effect?

Comment: @Verdan Yes some indeed do. Here are two examples, taken directly from the book, although worded differently. 

 1. The caster infuses themselves with water magic to
become super-humanly strong-willed. The spell lasts as
long as the pool is dedicated, and the caster may
increase their attribute up to their magic rating.


 2. The characters outline becomes hazy and indistinct,
and makes them much more difficult to assault with
ranged attacks. Their dodge is raised by 2 for as long as
the pool is pledged.